# unknown smd chip

Tags: pcb

Can someone help me identify the chip tagged with 0L321? It is part of a RCC switching power supply. It feeds the base of the 13003 NPN switch transistor.

[image: The chip]

[image: Backside]

[image: Upside]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/